# Http Request Cuts Data after Ampersand sign &

Tags: php, c++, wininet

I made a HTTP Request from a C++ Application using wininet and it works successfully to send data over to a php file using the following winapi functions

```
InternetOpen()
InternetConnect()
HttpOpebnRequest()
HttpSendRequest()
```

now It Sends the data over to a php file , fine and good but it doesnt Send all the parameters

for instance i have this parameter

```
username=jade101&password=svetlana123&submit=yes
```

It just sends only `username=jade101` and throws the rest away.

the php i used to recieve the data looks like this

```
<?php
$data = $_GET['info'];
$fp = fopen('logga.txt','a+');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

What am i not getting correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Primarily coding with CPP and having a fair knowledge of PHP, something that I can say looking at the limited code is the usage of $_GET.

How are you sending the data over to the php file? Is it by calling the PHP script itself by appending the string

"username=jade101&password=svetlana123&submit=yes"

to it?

Anyway, the $_GET will have to capture each variable separately. Something like:

```
$uname = $_GET['username'];    
$upass = $_GET['password'];    
$sflag = $_GET['submit'];
```

You can also try:

```
$data = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

To capture the complete URI starting from the script name and parse the string as you like later.

I don't see why the problem exists in C++ code, unless the send buffers were incorrectly used but that implementation is not visible in this code.